# SQL Server place first column data in all rows until next row has some values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of data that needs to be un-grouped based on logic like same column data needs to be placed in all rows until next row has some value.

```sql
A    | NULL
NULL | 1
NULL | 2
NULL | 3
B    | NULL
NULL | 4
NULL | 5
```

I need result back like:

```sql
A    | 1
A    | 2
A    | 3
B    | 4
B    | 5
```

So, basically all null values in 1st column needs to be filled with previous row 1st column data which is not null.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/688bb/1/0)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your data seems to be assuming an ordering.  But SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets.  You need an ordering column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself using the below query which produces the result I have been looking for:

```
SELECT
    T.ID
   ,COL1 = (SELECT TOP (1) T1.COL1
        FROM T AS T1
        WHERE T1.ID <= T.ID AND T1.COL1 IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY T1.ID DESC)
   ,COL2
FROM
    T
WHERE
    T.COL1 IS NULL
ORDER BY
    T.ID
```

Here is the db [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/688bb/6/0) with the working result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an ordering column, then with your sample data, you could use a cumulative max:

```
select max(col1) over (order by <order col>) as col1,
       max(col2) over (order by <order col>) as col2
from t;
```

`max()` may not actually be the right function -- because the fake data might just happen to be increasing.  If that is the case, you can instead do:

```
select max(col1) over (partition by oc_col1) as col1,
       max(col2) over (partition by oc_col2) as col2
from (select t.*,
             max(case when col1 is not null then <order col> end) over (order by <order col>) as oc_col1,
             max(case when col2 is not null then <order col> end) over (order by <order col>) as oc_col2
      from t
     ) t;
```

What you really want is `lag(ignore nulls)`.  However, SQL Server does not (yet) support that (standard) functionality.

EDIT:

You can easily handle a single `NULL` value at the beginning:

```
select max(col1) over (order by id) as col1,
       coalesce(max(col2) over (order by id),
                min(col2) over () - 1
               ) as col2
from t;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/688bb/5) is your db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution Gordon, but the output is not exactly the same that I am looking for. I have created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/688bb/1/0) for this. You can see there are some extra data like `|    A | (null) |` which I do not need and `|    B |      3 |` which is not correct. Could you please check this once. Do we need to update the query in some way to resolve these two issues.